# Excel Free Text Survey Analysis

Tags: microsoft-excel, survey

I have to analyze a survey. The survey consists of some yes/no questions, some numeric questions and some questions like the following (free text where respondents have entered multiple answers).

```
Do you have any social networking accounts (Facebook, Twitter, Myspace etc) Y N
If yes, which ones _____________________________
```

Respondents answer: **Facebook and Twitter**

How do I put these types of answer into Excel to gain some sort of useful analysis?

PS. I know Excel is not great for surveys, but can't spend $1000 on SPSS or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you asking your survey? Paper, email? You might look at one of the [free online survey tools](http://www.surveymonkey.com/), or something you can run on a Linux server (if you have access to one) like [LimeSurvey](http://www.limesurvey.org/) that will export results directly in Excel format and also give you stats on the screen too.

Comment: LimeSurvey will also export directly to SPSS.

Answer (score 2):

If you really insist on using Excel, you could try [CooWire](http://www.coowire.com/), or transforming your text data to numeric to be able to graph manually. E.g.: making Excel count the "Twitter" and "Facebook" words in a column and plot it.

I would rather use a software more comfortable with survey analyzing, and you do not have to pay for it by all means, look for the command-line [R](http://www.r-project.org/), [PSPP](http://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/) (a free alternative to SPSS) or any GUI to R, like Rcommander, R.net, RKWard and so on,